# Synchronization issues on a linked list data structure?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Lets suppose there are just 3 nodes in a linked list N0 , N1 , N2 and I want to acquire a lock on N2 using the following synchronized statement

```
synchronized(N1.next)
```

what will the above statement do, will it first lock N1 and then N1.next or will it directly lock N1.next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some strange ideas about how mutexes work; e.g. your previous question as well.

When you execute a `synchronized` method or a `synchronized` block, only one mutex is acquired; i.e. only one "thing" is locked.  And acquiring that mutex only affects other threads if they attempt to acquire *the same* mutex.

There is no "if I lock this, will it lock that as well".  That only happens if your application consistently uses a specific mutex / lock to mean that.

Comment: I got the point you are trying to convey, but the thing is if I acquire the lock on an object will it not implicitly lock all its members or do they have their individual locks to be acquired?

Comment: @AnkitSablok You don't lock objects. You acquire an object's lock or mutex. In your example code it would be the mutex of N1.next, i.e. N2. There is no implicit locking of members or any such nonsense.

Comment: @AnkitSablok I'm completely chill. Did you get the idea that I was upset about something?

Comment: yeah I thought you were upset, but yeah you made it clear to me :), thanks for that

Comment: @AnkitSablok - I believe I've already answered that for you.  At least twice.

Answer (score 0):

It will lock N1.next naturally, since that is the object specified.

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.19) is:

```
SynchronizedStatement:         
  synchronized ( Expression ) 
    Block
```

Further quoting:

> The type of Expression must be a reference type, or a compile-time
>   error occurs.
>
> A synchronized statement is executed by first **evaluating the
>   Expression.**
>
> If evaluation of the Expression completes abruptly for some reason,
>   then the synchronized statement completes abruptly for the same
>   reason.

So yes in your case whatever `N1.next` evaluates to, will act as a mutex.

Related JLS [§14.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) read.

Comment: but lets say in that time another thread tries to modify N1 when this thread tries to read the value of N1.next as N1.next is not an atomic operation, what will happen then?

Comment: Nothing. The contents of mutex are not important. Mutex is a key mechanism, all you care about is the key and not its appearance or other details.